# Azure Pipeline - Importing Taskgroup via json always creates a new one instead of changing the existing

Tags: json, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azureportal

I have created a Task Group in Azure Pipeline via the GUI.

Then, I exported the JSON.
Next, I have changed the `inputs` in the json.
Afterward, I wanted to import this new json to change the existing TaskGroup.

Result:
It didn't update the existing TaskGroup, instead, it created a new task group called the same but as postfix " - Copy".

Analyzed:
When I downloaded the new imported Task Group I have seen that the value of `Id` has changed.
Anyway, I could not found a way to update the existing TaskGroup, what do I have to change in my Json in order to alter and not to create a new one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [Taskgroups Update API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/taskgroups/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0).

Comment: Thanks Matt, I am sure this works!
Anyway, it would be nice if there is an easier way, like the already existing "Import" button if the JSON has the same `Id` like the existing one.

Comment: @AstralisSomnium. If it solved, you could mark it as answer to help more communities who have the same issue.  You also could give your [feedback or feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) to Azure Devops

Comment: Thanks for reminding, but unfortunately it didn't answer my question "to change an existing Taskgroup by importing via GUI."  Thanks for the link, I have created a issue here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/435277/change-an-existing-taskgroup-by-importing-via-gui.html